# MonteCarlo Markov Chain: Metropolis Hastings sampling

Tags: algorithms

I'm implementing the MCMC Metropolis Hastings algorithm for a Baynes net, and I am struggling with the acceptance parameter...

I've figured out that I can just use a standard normal distribution for the proposal probability, $$ q(x|x') $$ and use that to generate an $x(cand)$ ... but I can't find out/figure out for the life of me how exactly I am supposed to estimate $$\pi(x)$$ and $$ \pi(x') $$ or how I am supposed to multiply these values with $q(x|x')$ and $q(x'|x)$, given that these are distributions...

Please, any help would be appreciated.  I have the whole thing written, and it is driving me crazy that something this simple is stumping me.

The schema is simple: a set of nodes with four values according to a conditional discrete distribution, and a set of nodes which depend on two nodes of the prior set, with three values according to a conditional discrete distribution.

Comment: We typically know $\pi$ up to a constant factor, namely the normalization constant for the distribution. For instance this happens if $\pi$ is a Boltzmann distribution, which is a common situation in physical applications. In this case we really do know $\frac{\pi(x)}{\pi(x')}$ (since the constant factor cancels out) which is enough to run the Metropolis algorithm. If you don't even know $\pi$ to within a multiplicative constant then I would have to ask what you *do* know about $\pi$.

Comment: ok...what I do know about $\pi$...  I know nothing about $\pi$.  I mean, I probably do know something, but I am not aware that what I know pertains to $\pi$.  The schema is three teams with a conditional discrete distribution of probabilities of a certain skill level, and three matches between the teams with probabilities of win lose or tie depending on the skill level difference of the teams involved...

Comment: $\pi(x)$ I think would depend on a lot of things, and it would change depending on the node that changed the past round...so the probability of team A having skill 0, while the other teams have skill 1 and all the games were tied would be different, right? 

but I get the sense that $\pi$ is supposed to be a constant, or at least an approximation...

Comment: $\pi$ is one distribution, yes. But if you do not know $\pi$ then in some sense the Metropolis algorithm is the wrong thing. The whole point of the Metropolis algorithm is to take some perhaps nonsensical dynamics, then use a modification of those to get a Markov chain whose stationary distribution is $\pi$. In general this is all it does. Sometimes we read more into it, but this is fundamentally the purpose.

Comment: Can I just use the probabilities of the state of the individual variable being changed?  I mean, the probability of the state prior to the change is $P(x)\pi(X\x)$, and the probability of the state after the change is $P(x')\pi(X\x')$ where $X\x$ means $X$ without $x$...in this case, $\pi(X\_) / \pi(X\_)$ just cancels out and you are left with $P(x')/P(x)$??  

I mean, the only thing that needs to happen is that it converges...

Comment: I don't think I understand the setup of your problem. If you do not know $\frac{\pi(x)}{\pi(y)}$ for each $x,y$, then strictly speaking you are not running the Metropolis algorithm. In your case I do not think I understand what $P$ is, can you explain that?